# PHP sort by headers

Tags: php, sorting, html-table

How can I sort this table by columns - when I click on choosen header (names of headers would be links), table would sort by that header - column, in my PHP:

```
<?php
```

open text file (first row is of headers which are divided by ;)

```
$fp = fopen('C:\...\usedlicences.txt','r') or die("can't open file");
```

create table with border

```
echo "<table id='MyTable' border='1'>\n";
```

create header row for table with headers

```
echo "<td><b>id</b><td><b>name</b></td><td><b>surname</b></td><td><b>address</b></td><td><b>state</b></td><td><b>phone</b></td><td><b>city</b></td><td><b>date</b></td><td><b>color</b></td>";                          
$length = 1000;
$delimiter = ";";      
$k=1;
```

from file create rows and populate them with data (skip first (header) row) and add first column where id of row is written

```
$csv_line = fgetcsv( $fp, $length, $delimiter); 
while($csv_line = fgetcsv( $fp, $length, $delimiter ) ) {
echo "<tr>";            
echo "<td>$k</td>";
$k++;   
for ($i = 0, $j = count($csv_line); $i < $j; $i++) {
echo '<td>'.$csv_line[$i].'</td>';  
}
}
echo "<tr>";   
echo '</table>';
fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
?>
```

for showing alert how much licences are used (all rows minus header row)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var oRows = document.getElementById('MyTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
var iRowCount = oRows.length-1;
alert('Licences used: ' + ((iRowCount)-1)+'!');
</script>
```

test.txt looks like:

```
id;name;surname;address;state;phone;city;date;color
1;John;Simts;Yellow 12;Greenik;1234567;Mannds;12/3/1234;blue
```

Comment: Why don't you use something like YUI Datatables, which should be good enough to solve it. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/. Example here - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_basic_clean.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [making html table columns optionally sortable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4522890/), [sort listings, search results, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4663786/)

Comment: I solved it by using jQuery, thanks.